# How to authenticate from Java client for Wildfly web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wildfly-8, webservices-client

I want to implement a client application for an already deployed web-service. The web-service is deployed as ear on a Wildfly 8 server and running.
I generated the stub classes by parsing the web service's WSDL file with wsimport. I created a small client application that is using the generated stub classes to invoke methods on the server.

Now, my problem is, that the invocation of a method results in a security exception on Wildfly. The server.log says, that the authorization failed. I tried to add users with roles to Wildfly (*bin/add_user.sh*) but it does not work. I also tried to use MySQL users, because security domain says it uses Database Login module, but no success.

The error message in the *server.log* (shortened):

```
2015-07-15 17:25:19,732 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-3) PBOX000291: Method: getConfig, interface: ServiceEndpoint, required roles: Roles(user,)
2015-07-15 17:25:19,733 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-3) PBOX000292: Insufficient method permissions [principal: null, EJB name: VendorServiceBean, method: getConfig, interface: ServiceEndpoint, required roles: Roles(user,), principal roles: Roles(), run-as roles: null]
2015-07-15 17:25:19,733 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-3) PBOX000299: Required module org.jboss.security.authorization.modules.DelegatingAuthorizationModule failed
2015-07-15 17:25:19,745 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-3) PBOX000325: Authorization processing error: org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationException: PBOX000017: Acces denied: authorization failed 
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.authorization.JBossAuthorizationContext.invokeAuthorize(JBossAuthorizationContext.java:268) [picketbox-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
...
2015-07-15 17:25:19,757 TRACE [org.jboss.security.audit] (default task-3) [Failure]Source=org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper;Action=authorization;Exception:=PBOX000017: Acces denied: authorization failed ;Resource:=[org.jboss.security.authorization.resources.EJBResource:contextMap={policyRegistration=null}:method=public vendor.vendor.vendor.common.model.ConfigurationContainer vendor.vendor.vendor.service.impl.VendorServiceBean.getConfig():ejbMethodInterface=ServiceEndpoint:ejbName=VendorServiceBean:ejbPrincipal=null:MethodRoles=Roles(user,):securityRoleReferences=null:callerSubject=Subject:
    Principal: anonymous
:callerRunAs=null:callerRunAs=null:ejbRestrictionEnforcement=false:ejbVersion=2.0];policyRegistration=null;
2015-07-15 17:25:19,758 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-3) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
2015-07-15 17:25:19,758 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component VendorServiceBean for method public vendor.vendor.vendor.common.model.ConfigurationContainer vendor.vendor.vendor.service.impl.VendorServiceBean.getConfig(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public vendor.vendor.vendor.common.model.ConfigurationContainer vendor.vendor.vendor.service.impl.VendorServiceBean.getConfig() of bean: VendorServiceBean is not allowed
```

The security realm configuration in *standalone.xml* of Wildfly (as defined by web service vendor):

```
<security-realm name="VendorRealm">
    <authentication>
        <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
        <jaas name="vendor-security-domain"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

The security domain configuration in *standalone.xml* of Wildfly (as defined by web service vendor):

```
<security-domain name="vendor-security-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/VENDORDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM ACCOUNT WHERE username=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT name, 'Roles' FROM role r, account a, account_role ar WHERE a.username = ? AND ar.account_id = a.id AND r.id = ar.role_id"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="HEX"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

And my attempts to authenticate from Java client:

```
VendorServiceBeanService svc = new VendorServiceBeanService();
VendorService port = svc.getVendorServiceBeanPort();
( (BindingProvider) port ).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "theuser");  
( (BindingProvider) port ).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "thepassword"); 
port.getConfig();
```

So my question in short is: How can I authenticate at Wildfly from Java client?

I am new to Wildfly and web service client implementation. Maybe I just looked for the wrong terms.
I bet the answer to my question is pretty simple, but after hours of struggling through the web I go crazy. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you show the web service request? Where do you add the user id and password to the request?

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking about. I do not know where to put user and password. I use the web service stub directly in the Java client code with: `VendorServiceBeanService svc = new VendorServiceBeanService(); VendorService port = svc.getVendorServiceBeanPort();`

Comment: Though, I tried it in the Java client with: `( (BindingProvider) port ).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "theuser"); ( (BindingProvider) port ).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "thepassword");` but obviously it did not work. Server log says: `Insufficient method permissions [principal: null, EJB name: VendorServiceBean,`